# Secure part of Octopress

Tags: ruby, security, passwords, jekyll, octopress

I have an Octopress webpage in place and I want to block certain posts (some that only my family should be able to see) using a password (or something else) that I disseminate through email.

What's the best way to achieve this and also ensure that the posts don't show up in the archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For family posts you could put them in a separate directory and use `.htaccess` to password protect that directory.

For them not to show up in archives you would need to edit the theme.
The following is based on the classic theme:

Edit archives/index.html

```
---
layout: page
title: Blog Archive
footer: false
---

<div id="blog-archives">
{% for post in site.posts reverse %}
    {% if  post.categories contains 'noarchive' %}
    {% else %}
        {% capture this_year %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
        {% unless year == this_year %}
            {% assign year = this_year %}
            <h2>{{ year }}</h2>
        {% endunless %}
        <article>
            {% include archive_post.html %}
        </article>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

In the posts you don't want to show up in the archive the yaml section would look something like this:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Welcome"
date: 2013-02-07 00:00
comments: true
categories: 
 - site
 - noarchive
---
```